# Dynamically submitting tasks to ExecutorService based on condition

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I am currently using ExecutorServices with fixed thread pool and submitting 3 tasks.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

Future<Object1> = executorService.submit(task1);

Future<Object2> = executorService.submit(task2);

Future<Object3> = executorService.submit(task3);

executorService.shutdown();

executorService.awaitTermination(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

Now this works perfectly as i always had the requirement to execute all these differences 3 services, but now i want to customize it. 
For instance i may just need to run service 1, service 2, service 3 or any combination of them or all of them.

How can i customize which all services I want to submit for exectution and the thread pool size ?

I am not interested in doing creepy `if` checks around to check if service 1 required etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm thinking you'll want to do is abstract out your access to the `ExecutorService` and pass in the tasks you want it to work on dynamically.

Note that I'm not making any guarantees or promises of performance here; this is the concept one would want to think along the lines of at least.

Provided that I am sure that I want to tear down the thread pool every time, I can dynamically set the size of the thread pool to the size of the tasks passed in.

```
public void executeTasks(Callable<?>... tasks) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(tasks.length);
    for(Callable<?> task : tasks) {
        executorService.submit(task);
    }

    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.awaitTermination(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Provided you handle the `InterruptedException`, you could invoke it thus:

```
obj.executeTaks(future1, future3);
```

Comment: I like the idea, and i am considering it if we can supply the order also. Lets suppose task 1 &  2 to have a '1' batch number, and then task 3 to have batch number 2. Batch with less number ( eg. 1) executes first parallelising the tasks for that batch number. Once that batch number finishes, then tasks for next batch. Is that also feasible ?

Comment: @NoviceUser:  If you create a custom method which allows you to specify a list of work orders which contain a callable and a batch number, sure.  Basically, you can do kind of whatever you like, since you've abstracted out the ExecutorService piece; you can pass in what you need to the method and have the method concern itself with those other fiddly requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Would this satisfy your requirements:

```
List<Runnable> servicesToRun = new ArrayList<>();
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(servicesToRun.size());
servicesToRun.stream().forEach(executorService::submit);
```

Then it's just a matter of making sure the `List` named `servicesToRun` contains the services that you want to run, depending on your application logic.